# Objective C: How to synchronize two threads without busy waiting

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronization

I am looking at the following interview question:  Suppose you have two threads, one that prints odd numbers from  1 to 100 and other that prints even numbers.

How can you synchronize the two threads such that numbers are printed in order from 1 to 100 (i.e printed as 1, 2, 3,...,100).

Hint says:  You should avoid busy-waiting anti-pattern (i.e waste CPU resources by using a lock).  Looks like in Java, this is solved by using wait() and notify().

My questions are:
1.  What is the equivalent mechanism in Objective-C?  Do I really need to look into NSTHread or is there something in GCD/KVO etc I can use.
2. Is it really inefficient to use locks in this case, since the wait will probably be only for very period of time (i.e is it better to do this and go through overhead of notifications etc).

Comment: Semaphores do not busy-wait.  Locks (as in `NSLock`) are semaphores.

Comment: why are you tagging Java?